# Can't assign debounce to class property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, debouncing

I'm using Babel with Stage 2 preset and  have a React component class like this:

```
class Test extends Component {
  someValue = 'Hello';

  componentDidMount() {
    this.debouncedHandleResize = debounce(this.handleResize, 1000);
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.debouncedHandleResize);
  }

  handleResize = () => {
    console.log(this.someValue);
  }
}
```

This works as expected. 1000ms after a window resize the handleResize method fires and console logs 'Hello'.

Why can I not do the follow though?

```
class Test extends Component {
  someValue = 'Hello';

  debouncedHandleResize = debounce(this.handleResize, 1000);

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.debouncedHandleResize);
  }

  handleResize = () => {
    console.log(this.someValue);
  }
}
```

In this scenario I get an error:

```
TypeError: Expected a function
```

I must be missing something, but I thought both were basically ways of assigning a property value to the class.

Comment: seems weird you would have handleResize multiple times....

Comment: The code works fine when I run it in a stack snippet.

Comment: @epascarello My apologies, I had a couple of typos in there. I've corrected them now.

Comment: `console.log('this.handleResize', this.handleResize); debouncedHandleResize = debounce(this.handleResize, 1000);`

Comment: `debounce` won't cause the error you've mentioned, there's no such problem with it (except that you didn't bind neither debouncedHandleResize nor handleResize). Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have updated the code: The problem is that both `debouncedHandleResize` and `handleResize` are public class fields. Because the `debouncedHandleResize` assignment comes first, you are trying to reference `handleResize` before it exists.

Public class fields are evaluated in order, so

```
class Test {
  debouncedHandleResize = debounce(this.handleResize, 1000);

  handleResize = () => {
    console.log(this.someValue);
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.debouncedHandleResize = debounce(this.handleResize, 1000);

    this.handleResize = () => {
      console.log(this.someValue);
    }
}
```

It should be obvious why this cannot work.

### Solution

Change the order of the assignments:

```
class Test {
  handleResize = () => {
    console.log(this.someValue);
  }
  debouncedHandleResize = debounce(this.handleResize, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Strangely I didn't actually know this. Because I'm so used to referencing methods in the constructor to bind `this`, even though those methods are declared after the constructor. I guess in that situation the references are inside the method, not at the top level. Thanks for your help.

Comment: “even though those methods are declared after the constructor” but “normal” class methods (`foo() {}`) are defined on the prototype, which is already set when the constructor is executed. That’s the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it should be:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That might indeed be the issue. At least that would explain the error.

Comment: Apologies, it was a typo in my question. Fixed now. I still have the same error. It seems I can bind the debounce function to a class property the standard way, but not the new way.

Comment: @Coop: As I have said, your code works fine when I tested it. Double check that the typo is not in your actual code as well. The error fits (well, depending on the browser you use maybe).

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the help but this wasn't the issue. I've discovered what the problem was and will post as an answer to help other.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered where the problem is. In my second example (the one that throws an error), the class property is set like this:

```
debouncedHandleResize = debounce(this.handleResize, 1000);
```

The error is complaining for some reason that it doesn't like `this.handleResize` and says it's not a function. Whilst I don't 100% understand this, a simple test of manually passing in a function instead removed the error:

```
debouncedHandleResize = debounce(() => false, 1000);
```

With this knowledge, my new and successful way to write the class is:

```
class Test extends Component {
  someValue = 'Hello';

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  handleResize = debounce(() => console.log(this.someValue), 1000)
}
```

Comment: Now that you have provided your actual code, the issue is quite obvious. See my answer.